# Indicate action only effects the current page

Tags: usability, interaction-design, pagination, deletion

A user will be able to click a link in the th of a table (table holds list of products) to clear all inputs in table column.

If there are more than a certain amount of products, the table will be split up with pagination. When you click the link in the th, only the inputs on the current page will be cleared. What would the clearest link text for this instance be?[image]

Comment: Clearing just a single page is not intuitive, especially if you place it on header. We would need some more information of the functionality to come up with suggestions. Right now, I am confused why such a functionality is needed.

Answer (score 1):

It is always hard to be really clear with buttons. It is almost impossible to explain yourself in about 10 characters in this case.

If it needs to be realll short, you could do: **clear 
view**

If you can play with font size you could try to fit in: **reset this page**

Alternatively if you have the variable name that tells you the the amount of items on that page, or the number of pages, you could print something like: **clear page 1/2**

Answer (score 0):

**Clear Values** would be good as the link text to remove all the current column entries from current page.